# Add a repeated image in front of a html tag video

Tags: html, css, html5-video, overlay

I created a div with a video and in front of the video I want to add a repeated png image (small squares 1x1px).

HTML

```
<div id="video-background"></div>
<div id="video-wrap">
    <video id="loop-video" loop preload="auto" src="vid.mp4" autoplay>
    </video>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#video-background {
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background-image: url('../img/imgtrama.png');
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
#video-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}
#video-wrap #loop-video {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

It doesn't matter where I put my squared background, I always see the video without it.

I tried playing with the z-index but it is not working.

Comment: You need to put `#video-background ` **inside** `#video-wrap`. Start there, That's the way overlays work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, put the `#video-background` div within the `#video-wrap` div.  I have also adjusted some of the CSS to make it work:

```css
#video-background {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/50x50');
  background-repeat: repeat;
  opacity: .8;
}
#video-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#video-wrap #loop-video {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="video-wrap">
    <video id="loop-video" loop preload="auto" src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" autoplay></video>
    <div id="video-background"></div>
</div>
```